# How do I declare a generic parameter in F#?

Tags: f#, value-restriction

Given the following code:

```
let DisplayImpl logger data =
    data |> Seq.iter logger
    printfn ""

let Working =
    DisplayImpl (printfn "%O") [1;2;3]
    DisplayImpl (printfn "%O") ["a";"b";"c"]

let NotWorking display =
    display (printfn "%O") [1;2;3]
    display (printfn "%O") ["a";"b";"c"]
                            ~~~ ~~~ ~~~
```

The last line gives the error: `This expression was expected to have type int but here has type string`

I thought the following might work, but it doesn't:

```
let StillNotWorking (display: ('a -> unit) -> seq<'a> -> unit) =
```

My question is, how do I define the NotWorking function so that the display parameter stays generic within the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions that are passed as arguments to other functions (like your `display`) cannot be themselves polymorphic in F#. They can use the generic type parameter (`'a` etc.), but the actual type for this parameter is specified when the main function (`NotWorking` in your case) is called. This means that you can only call `display` with single actual type used for the type variable `'a` in the body of `NotWorking`.

As a workaround, you can use an interface with a generic method:

```
type Displayer = 
  abstract Display : (obj -> unit) -> 'T list -> unit
 
let NotWorking (display:Displayer) = 
    display.Display (printfn "%O") [1;2;3] 
    display.Display (printfn "%O") ["a";"b";"c"]
```

The method `Display` of the interface is itself generic method, so you can call that method multiple times with different type arguments (`int` in the first case and `string` in the second).

However, I didn't find this a limitation when writing normal code in F# very often, so maybe there is an easier solution for your problem (possibly, taking a non-generic `IEnumerable` or something simple like that - or `obj list` as in the answer from John). If you give more details about your actual code, that would be useful.

**Some background**, just in case you're interested in theoretical details, but none of this is really something that would be important in day-to-day real world F# programming. Anyway -

This is possible in other langauges like Haskell and the mechanism that allows it is called *universal types*. When you have a polymorphic function in F#, it essentially means that that the scope of the type variables is the entire function, so `('a -> unit) -> unit` can be viewed as `forall 'a . ('a -> unit) -> unit`.

When you call the function, you need to specify what `'a` is and that cannot be changed (i.e. you can't use the function `'a -> unit` that you get as an argument with two different types for `'a` once `'a` is fixed).

Using universal types, you can write `forall` yourself, so you can say that the type is:
`(forall 'a . 'a -> unit) -> unit`. Now the generic parameter `'a` is only linked to the function that you'll get as an argument. The type of the function given as an argument is now itself a generic function and so you can call it with different types standing for `'a`.

PS: Value restriction is a different problem - that essentially means that F# cannot make things that are not syntactic functions generic, but in your example, you're writing syntactic functions, so that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 5):

This works as well

```
let NotWorking (display:(obj -> unit) -> obj list -> unit) =
    display (printfn "%O") [1;2;3]
    display (printfn "%O") ["a";"b";"c"]
```

Comment: +1 This is definitely the simplest way to solve it in practice. I can't imagine a scenario where you'd actually need a generic `display` function as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it definitely solved the problem as stated, however I had oversimplified my problem and ran into covariance problems (I think) in my real code.  This method is definitely much simpler and in general should solve a large proportion of similar problems.